# C++, const методы

Tags: c++, const

Рассмотрим пример:

```
class A
{
    public:
    float *GetValues() const
    {
        return values;
    }
    private:
    float values[10];
};
```

Законно ли в этом случае считать метод константным? Ведь сам он не меняет состояние класса, но предоставляет указатель на массив, и кто-то может изменить содержимое массива через этот указатель.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, незаконно.

Мой GCC выдает `error: invalid conversion from 'const float*' to 'float*'`.

Внутри константного метода все поля (кроме `mutable`) считаются константными, так что `values` имеет тип `const float [10]`. Без `const_cast` он в `float *` не преобразуется.

---

Но если бы у вас в классе хранился не массив, а указатель - `float *`, то в константном методе он имел бы тип `float *const` (константный указатель на изменяемые `float`), а не `const float *` (изменяемый указатель на константные `float`). Такой указатель преобразовывался бы `float *` без проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы метод был законно константным, нужно чуть изменить код - возвращайте из вашего метода указатель на константу (const float*), а не просто указатель (float*):

```
class A
{
    public:
    const float *GetValues() const
    {
        return values;
    }
    private:
    float values[10];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что компилятор не даст вам так просто неявно преобразовать `const float[10]` в `float*` - вам придется выполнять приведение... Но при этом вы получите сообщение о том, что нельзя преобразовать константный массив в неконстантный указатель.

Так что да - такой метод не может быть константным. И поведение компилятора, который этот код компилировать не станет, это подтверждает :)

P.S. Конечно, компилятор можно уговорить кодом наподобие

```
return const_cast<float*>(values);
```

Но тогда уже **вы** отвечаете за то, что возвращаемым указателем никто не воспользуется неподобающим образом...